# Solution of exact diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Perhaps this question is a little silly , but I'm making an exact differential equation and comparing the solution I got with the solution of the book.
I realize that they are different.

This is the equation:

$$
\left(1-2x^{2}-2y\right)\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=4x^{3}+4xy
$$

The solution I get is:

$$x^{4}+2x^{2}y-y+y^{2}=C$$

and the solution of my book is:

$$-x^{4}-2x^{2}y+y-y^{2}=C$$

The solutions are equivalent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes of course because a constant $C$ that takes all real values can be called $-C'$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$-x^{4}-2x^{2}y+y-y^{2}=C$$
$$-\left(x^{4}+2x^{2}y-y+y^{2}\right)=C$$
$$x^{4}+2x^{2}y-y+y^{2}=-C$$
Since $-C$ is also a constant, then
$$x^{4}+2x^{2}y-y+y^{2}=C$$
So yes both solutions are in fact equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent as $C$ is representing some constant, hence the first can be written as $-C=-x^4-2x^2y+y-y^2$, and we can have $-C = C_0$ where $C_0$ is a new constant.